# Should I make separate instance of HttpClient for each request

Tags: android, apache

My app is to send multiple http requests for fetching data. 
Every request must to be executed concurrently. 
Since, There is only one HttpClient's object for each concurrently executed request. Would there be any issues that may affect the concurrency.

Comment: Well am not very sure on it. But AFAIK you can send concurrent http request but it may divide your bandwidth. Furhter there is limitiation of live httpclient connections. If you share some code that will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

HttpClient is kind of an oddball on Android. In the past I used a pool with threads to have multiple and/or concurrent connections.

However Koushik Dutta (from CyanogenMod, ClockworkMod) made a very nice [AsyncHttp](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync) library. The library is very simple to use and probably will handle all of your needs.